# ProgressBar not shown when okhttp client enqueues a request

Tags: android, android-progressbar, okhttp

I have this code when button is clicked:

```
final Button btnInvia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInvia);
btnInvia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        btnInvia.setEnabled(false);

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);

        Evento evento = new Evento(PushToTalkActivity.this, Constants.TIPO_EVENTO_ID_PUSH_TO_TALK);
        evento.setFile(BinaryHelper.binaryToString(mFileName));

        RESTClient.pushToTalk(PushToTalkActivity.this, evento, new Callback<BaseResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<BaseResponse> call, Response<BaseResponse> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    Toast.makeText(PushToTalkActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.inizio_lavoro_inviato), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    TransitionBuilder.with(PushToTalkActivity.this).clearStack().show(MainActivity.class);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<BaseResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnInvia.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

My problem is that ProgressBar is not shown until RESTClient is enqueued, not before.
If I comment the RESTClient call the progressBar is shown correctly.

This is the xml of layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".activities.PushToTalkActivity">a

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recording"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/registazione_in_corso" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgBtnAzione"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/stop_recording_icon" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnInvia"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="@string/invia" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The pushToTalk function is simple:

```
NetworkManager.getRESTService().pushToTalk(
            getAuthToken(context),
            new Gson().toJson(evento)
    ).enqueue(new Callback<BaseResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<BaseResponse> call, Response<BaseResponse> response) {
            //if (validateResponse(context, response.code(), response.message())) {
            if (validateResponse(context, response)) {
                callback.onResponse(call, response);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<BaseResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            showFailure(context, t.getMessage());
            callback.onFailure(call, t);
        }
    });
```

I do not why my ProgressBar is not immediately shown after button is clicked.

Comment: You are making invisible the bar in failure.

Comment: @ShaluTD can you explain better please? I did not understand

Comment: `mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in onFailure()

Comment: when exactly is the progressBar shown ??

Comment: @SantanuSur I do not know exactly, but after seconds.

Comment: i mean before the call or after the call ??

Comment: problem solved?

Comment: and also are you sure.. if you comment out the rest call the progress bar shows correctly ?? because your code looks perfect !!

Comment: @SantanuSur seconds after the RESTClient call.

Comment: I think your `RESTClient.pushToTalk()` is synchronous and is blocking the UI thread, that's why